# Send SQL Server Email With Attachment Without Using sysadmin privilege

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I am trying to send an email using the `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure of SQL Server with an attachement,

My account doesn't have `sysadmin` privileges, when an attachement is sent as normal SQL Server user, I get this error

> The client connection security context could not be impersonated. 
>   Attaching files requires an integrated client login

Is there is any way to send SQL Server email with attachement without using `sysadmin` privileges?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you would have looked at the [MSDN documentation for sp_send_dbmail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx), it says:

> *Database Mail uses the Microsoft Windows security context of the current user to control access to files. Therefore, **users who are authenticated with SQL Server Authentication cannot attach files using @file_attachments**. Windows does not allow SQL Server to provide credentials from a remote computer to another remote computer. Therefore, Database Mail may not be able to attach files from a network share in cases where the command is run from a computer other than the computer that SQL Server runs on.*

So from this it's clear you have to be connected to SQL Server using **Windows authentication** (with `Integrated Security=SSPI;` in your connection string) in order to be able to attach files to e-mails.

Comment: I'm looking at the same problem and am using mapped credentials. I have found that it DOES work if the sql login has sysadmin privs. but not without.

Answer (score -1):

This will solve the problem , you just need to provide sysadmin rights to the sql user ,
Command : 
sp_addsrvrolemember  'User', 'sysadmin'